# Template novice

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on a program involving the use of templates to evaluate postfix expressions.  I'm not allowed to modify the code in any way; only fill in the blanks, so to speak (most of which have been filled, but errors are turning up).  This being said:

1) The template header, template specialization, and main program files are all separate.  How do I implement the template in the main program?  I'm already using #include  at the end of the header file as the specialization substitute.

2) FIXED

3) In the specialization file, do I need to use #include "templateheader.h" above using namespace std, or do I just put template  above every function?  I'll post an example as I have it now below.

Two asterisks mark the lines where we have to fill in the blanks.  If it's only part of a line, it's one star on each side.

stackType.h

```
#pragma once**
//   Catherine Stringfellow and Trey Brumley
//   A Stack is a ???**

//   Class specification for Stack ADT in file StackType.h
using namespace std;

static const int MAXITEMS = 50;

template <class stack>**
class StackType
{
  public:
    // Class constructors
    StackType();
    StackType (const StackType & other);

    void makeEmpty();
    // Function:  Sets stack to an empty state.
    // Post: Stack is empty.

    bool isFull() const;
    // Function: Determines whether the stack is full.
    // Pre:  Stack has been initialized.
    // Post: Function value = (stack is full)

    bool isEmpty() const;
    // Function: Determines whether the stack is empty.
    // Pre:  Stack has been initialized.
    // Post: Function value = (stack is empty)

    void push(*stack* item);
    // Function: Adds newItem to the top of the stack.
    // Pre:  Stack has been initialized.
    // Post: If (stack is full), PushOnFullStack exception is thrown;
    //       otherwise, newItem is at the top of the stack.

    void pop(*stack* & item);
    // Function: Removes top item from the stack and returns it in item.
    // Pre:  Stack has been initialized.
    // Post: If (stack is empty), PopOnEmptyStack exception is thrown;
    //       otherwise, top element has been removed from stack.
    //       item is a cop of the removed item.

    int getStackNum ();
    //Function: returns the number of items in the stack
    //Pre: Stack has been initialized
    //Post: Returns the number of items in the stack

private:
    int top;
    stack items[MAXITEMS];  //statically allocated array
};

#include "stackType.cpp";**
```

stackType.cpp

```
// Catherine Stringfellow and Trey Brumley
// File: StackType.cpp

// Templated member function implementations for class StackType. 
// This is the statically allocated array-based stack.

#include "stack"**
using namespace std;

template <class stack>**
StackType *StackType<stack>*::StackType()
{
  top = -1;
}

template <class stack>**
StackType *StackType<stack>*::StackType (const StackType & other)
{
  top = other.top;
  for (int i=0; i < top; i++)
      items[i] = other.items[i];
}

template <class stack>**
StackType*<stack>*::makeEmpty()
{
  top = -1;
}

template <class stack>**
*bool StackType<stack>*::isEmpty() const
{
  return (top == -1);
}

template <class stack>**
bool StackType*<stack>*::isFull() const
{
  return (top == MAXITEMS-1);
}

template <class stack>**
StackType*<stack>*::push(StackType newItem)
{
  if( !isFull() )
  {
    top++;
    items[top] = newItem;
  }
}

template <class stack>**
StackType*<stack>*::pop( & item)
{
  if( !isEmpty() )
  {
    item = items[top];
    top--;
  }
}

template <class stack>**
int StackType*<stack>*::getStackNum ()
{
   return top+1;  
}
```

main

```
/*  Erik Malone and Catherine Stringfellow and Trey Brumley                 Date: December-5-2013
    File: prog5.cpp

    Program Specifications
       Narrative:   Program that evaluates and converts postfix expressions.
       Interface:
          Introductory Screen:
               "Postfix Calculator and Converter"
          Exit Screen:
               "Goodbye..."
          Input: 
                numbers in expressions should be separated by a space.
                (from keyboard, see attached)

          Output: 
                (all to screen, see attached)   
       Constants: 
          STACK_MAX
*/

#include "stack"**
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

int getValidChoice ();
/* purpose: get valid option choice from menu
   prereq: NONE
   postcond: int (for a valid choice returned)
*/

void readString(string& s);
/* purpose: Reads a line into a string
   recieves: string <s>
   returns: NONE
*/
void printString(const string& s);
/* purpose: Prints a string
   recieves: const string <s>
   returns: NONE
*/
void convertPostfix(string& post, string& result);
/* purpose: converts a prefix expression to infix
   recieves: string <post>, string <result>
   returns: NONE
*/
void convert(StackType & s, char ch);
/* purpose: pops two operands off a string stack and pushes the result
   recieves: string <post>, char <ch>
   returns: NONE
*/
void evalPostfix(string& post, double& answer);
/* purpose: calculates the value of the prefix expression
   recieves: string <post>, double <answer>
   returns: NONE
*/
void evaluate(StackType & s, char ch);
/* purpose: pops two operands off a double stack and pushes the result
   recieves: Stack <s>, char <ch>
   returns: NONE
*/

void error(int m);
//prints an error message, based on int parametet

//print the introduction and exit screens
void intro();
void outro();

void main()
{                   
    string post;
    double answer;
    int choice;

    //intro screen  
    intro();

    //while user wants to continue
    choice = getValidChoice();
    while (choice != 3) {

        //switch menu options
       switch (choice)                          
        {
        case 1: 
            cout<<"Please enter a postfix expression: ";
            readString(post);
            if (post == "")                             //error if string empty 
                error(1);
            else
            {
                evalPostfix(post, answer);
                printString(post);
                cout<<" = "<<answer<< endl << endl;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"Please enter a postfix expression: ";
            readString(post);
            if (post == "")
                error(1);
            else
            {   string tempString = "";
                convertPostfix(post, tempString);
                cout<<"Postfix expression: ";
                printString(post);
                cout<<"\nEpression converted to infix: "<<tempString << endl<<endl;
            }
            break;
            default:    //if choice is not recognized print error
              error(3);
      } //end switch

       choice = getValidChoice();
    } //end while

    outro();    

    //exit screen on return
    system("pause");
}

int getValidChoice ()
{                                                       
    int choice;

    //display menu options
    cout<<" Options                               \n";
    cout<< "  (1) Evaluate postfix expression  " << endl;
    cout<< "  (2) Convert postfix to infix   " << endl;
    cout<< "  (3) Quit      " << endl;

    //get menu option
    cout<<"Enter option: ";
    cin>>choice;
    cout <<endl;

    //validate menu option
    while ((choice < 1) || (choice > 3)) {
        cout << "Enter a value between 1 and 3: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }

    return choice;
}

void printString(const string& s)
{
    if (s.empty()) 
        cout<<"Empty";                                  //if string is empty print "empty"
    else
        cout<<s;
}

void readString(string& s)
{
    char temp[40];
    cin.ignore(80,'\n');                                //clear buffer
    cin.getline(temp, 40);                              //copy line to string
    s = temp;
}

void evalPostfix(string& post, double& answer)
{
    int index = 0, total = 0;                   
    double tempDbl;
    bool negative = false;              //to detect negative signs
    StackType s;                        //declare a stack of doubles 

    //loop index until end of string
    while (index < (int) post.length())                     
    {
        //pass over spaces in string
        while (isspace(post[index]))                    
            index++ ;   

        //if operator evaluate incrementing index
        if (!isdigit(post[index]) && 
            !((index+1 < (int) post.length()) && 
              (post[index] == '-' && isdigit(post[index+1]))))
        //if (!isdigit(post[index]))
            evaluate(s, post[index++]);                 
        else
        {   //if number, checks for negative sign
            if (post[index] == '-')                     
            {
                index++;
                negative = true;
            }

            //add up the digits from string
            while ((post[index] >= '0') && (post[index] <= '9'))
                total = (total * 10) + (post[index++] - '0');

            //if there was a negative sign, negate total
            if (negative)                               
            {
                total = total * -1;
                negative = false;
            }

            //push number onto stack
            s.push(total);                              
            total = 0;  
        }

        index++;
    }

    //pop answer from stack
    s.pop(tempDbl);                                     
    answer = tempDbl;

}

void evaluate(StackType  & s, char ch)
{
    double op1, op2;                                    

    //check if empty before popping operands
    if (!s.isEmpty())                                   
    {
        s.pop(op2);

        if (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            s.pop(op1);

            //push result
            switch(ch)                                  
            {
            case '+':
                s.push(op1 + op2);                      
                break;
            case '-':
                s.push(op1 - op2);
                break;
            case '*':
                s.push(op1 * op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                s.push(op1 / op2);
                break;
            default:
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void convertPostfix(string& post, string& result)
{
    int index = 0;
    string tempString;
    StackType s;  //declare a stack of strings

    //loop index until end of string
    while (index < (int) post.length())                     
    {
        //pass over spaces in string
        if (isspace(post[index]))                       
            index++ ;   

        //if operator convert incrementing index
        if (!isdigit(post[index]) && 
            !((index+1 < (int) post.length()) && 
              (post[index] == '-' && isdigit(post[index+1]))))
        //if (!isdigit(post[index]))
            convert(s, post[index++]);                  
        else
        {
            //clear string
            tempString.erase();                         

            //concatenate numbers to string
            while (!isspace(post[index]))               
                tempString = tempString + post[index++];

            //push string onto stack
            s.push(tempString);                         
        }

        index++;
    }
    //pop resulting string from stack
    s.pop(result);                                      
}

void convert(StackType  & s, char ch)
{
    string op1, op2, tempString;

    //check if empty before popping
    if (!s.isEmpty())                                   
    {
        s.pop(op2);

        if (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            s.pop(op1);

            //constructing string for result
            tempString = tempString + "( ";             
            tempString = tempString + op1;              

            //concatenate sign to string
            switch(ch)                                  
            {
            case '+':   
                tempString = tempString + " + ";        
                break;
            case '-':
                tempString = tempString + " - ";
                break;
            case '*':
                tempString = tempString + " * ";
                break;
            case '/':
                tempString = tempString + " / ";
                break;
            default:
                return;
            }

            //adding rest of the string
            tempString = tempString + op2;              
            tempString = tempString + " )";

            //push resulting string onto stack
            s.push(tempString);                         
        }
    }
}

void error(int m)
{
    system("cls");          //clear screen
    cout<<"\a";             //system beep

    //displays error message according to parameter passed
    switch (m)                                          
    {
    case -1:
        cout<<"INTERNAL ERROR";
        break;
    case 1:
        cout<<"ERROR - Postfix expression empty.";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"ERROR - invalid entry."; 
        break;
    default:
        cout <<"UNKNOWN ERROR.";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void intro()
{
    system("cls");                                      //clear screen
    //displays welcome message
    cout<<"Postfix Calculator and Converter\n\n";
}

void outro()
{
    cout<<"Goodbye...\n\n";                             //display exit message
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're allowed to change. And putting "#include "stackType.cpp";" at the end of a header file is wrong. Maybe you could write your own code -- something short and simple -- that would illustrate the concept you're trying to understand, then we could help you to get *that* working.

Comment: 1) Putting the include at the end of the header file does appear to work , and it was how we were told to do it, saying it was essentially the same as putting all of the specialization after the actual header, while keeping them in separate files.

2) I'll put two stars (**) next to all the places where we have to fill in.

Comment: Is this for the INFO 3200 class at Auburn University?

Comment: @Potatoswatter No, it's a school in Texas.  I'm just an Auburn fan.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2) it has to be std::string, or you could say

```
using std::string;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
```

and then you should be able to say just string. I would recommend the former, unless you are pulling in a lot of stuff from std::

Other bits of trivia:

- name your header file “stack.h”
- you do not need a stack.cpp, just implement the functions in stack.h, e.g.

  template 
  class Stack {
     ….
     void doSomething(ElementType& object) {…}
   ….
   };

This tends to be cleaner. You could also do it out of line but it still needs to be in the same file, and if you do it out-of-line, you need to prefix every function with the template keyword

- you might want to pick a better more descriptive name than “stack” for the template argument.

Comment: Adding the std namespace fixed point 2.  I think I removed it when it started turning up errors, but I removed it from teh wrong file and forgot to put it back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch the name of your class with the name of the template argument, that would make more sense. This would become

```
template <typename StackType>
class Stack 
{
...
};
```

For example

```
void push(stack item);
```

Would be

```
void push(StackType item);
```

1) You can put the declaration and the definition of the methods into separate files but you need to include them at the end like you did but I suggest your rename you stack.cpp to stack.inl (.inl for inline) or something else.

3) If you use 2 files like above there's no need to include stack.h inside stack.cpp/inl. Think of this like it's the same file. And be careful with that using namespace std since everyone that include your stack.h will be "using namespace std" and that might cause issues...

Finally, there's no template specialization in your source code and there's is no such thing as specialization file. However, template specialization do exist and it's probably not what you expect. More info [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)